# Attachment page per category

Tags: categories, attachments

I want to display a custom attachment page for a specific category, i.e. attachment page for category `wallpapers` should have a different template than category `cars`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachments does not have categories, so a simple `in_category()` or `has_category()` check will not work. What we will need to do to solve is this issue is the following

- Get the current attachment object. We will make use of `get_queried_object()` which will hold the current post object of the attachment being viewed
- Determine the post parent of the current attachment. This is easy, from `get_queried_object()` we will make use of the `post_parent` property which stores the ID of the post the attachment belongs to
- We will then use `has_category()` to determine if the attachment's parent has the desired category
- All of this info will be used inside `attachment_template` where we will set a specific template if an attachment parent is in the required category

You can do the following: (***NOTE:*** The following code is untested and requires at least PHP5.4)

```
add_filter( 'attachment_template', function ( $template )
{
    // Get the current attachment object
    $attachment = get_queried_object();

    // Check if current attachment's parent is attached to our desired category or not
    if ( 
         !has_category( // If our parent does not have this category, return 
            1, // Category id, or name or slug, change as needed
            $attachment->post_parent // The id from the post parent
         )
    ) 
        return $template;

    // We have made it to here, lets set the new template for this attachment
    // Check if the template exist before we add it
    $locate_template = locate_template( 'image-mycategory.php'); // Change as needed
    if ( !$locate_template )
       return $template;

    // YEAH, everything checks out, finaly. Set the new template
    return $template = $locate_template;
});
```

I have commented the code for easy following, and I also have added where you should change value to suite your needs

### EDIT

If you need to set the same template for multiple categories, you can just extend the `in_category()` check. `in_category()` accepts an array of category ID's, names, and slugs. Something like the following would work

```
    if ( 
         !has_category( // If our parent does not have this category, return 
            [1, 2, 3] // Array of category id's, or names or slugs, change as needed
            $attachment->post_parent // The id from the post parent
         )
    ) 
        return $template;
```

If you need to extend this to set different templates for different categories, we need a few more checks

```
add_filter( 'attachment_template', function ( $template )
{
    // Get the current attachment object
    $attachment = get_queried_object();

    /**
     * Check if current attachment's parent is attached to our desired category or not and set template part
     * For example, templates will be image-cars.php and image-tech.php, so our
     * $parts will be cars and tech
     */
    $part = '';

    // Check for cars category and set $part
    if ( 
         has_category( // If our parent have this category, set template part
            1, // Category id, or name or slug, change as needed
            $attachment->post_parent // The id from the post parent
         )
    ) 
        $part = 'cars';

    // Check for tech category and set $part
    if ( 
         has_category( // If our parent have this category, set template part
            2, // Category id, or name or slug, change as needed
            $attachment->post_parent // The id from the post parent
         )
    ) 
        $part = 'tech';

    // Check if $part have a value, if not, bail
    if ( !$part )
        return $template;

    // We have made it to here, lets set the new template for this attachment
    // Check if the template exist before we add it
    $locate_template = locate_template( "image-$part.php"); // Change as needed
    if ( !$locate_template )
       return $template;

    // YEAH, everything checks out, finally. Set the new template
    return $template = $locate_template;
});
```

Comment: Tnx Pieter it Works!

Is this work only for one specific template..ie Wallpapers...what if you also wanna set for few more categories? ie Cars, Tech...you just need to repeat if statement or?

Comment: I  have added an edit with the desired added part. Hope that helps. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Pieter, this is what I ask..tnx so much!... Maybe one day wordpress will implement this feature ;)

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. Enjoy ;-)